# Google Datalab, how to forbid users to connect to VM using --no-user-checking

Tags: security, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-datalab

we have several datalab users who has their own Datalab VM to connect and work with Notebooks. the connect to their vm using the followin command:

```
datalab connect <USER_VM_NAME>
```

But still they can connect to VM of other users using the following command:

```
datalab connect <ANOTHER_USER_VM_NAME> --no-user-checking
```

How this can be forbidden by setting a configuration on datalab?
if it is not possibile, how we can audit it to find out when a user used VM of another user?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by specifying the **[--service-account](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/reference/command-line/create#--service-account_service_account)** flag when you create Datalab instances.

You will need few more steps before, see detailed steps [here](https://github.com/googledatalab/datalab/issues/1203).

Create Datalab instance:

```
datalab create --project <PROJECT> --zone <ZONE> --for-user <TEAM_MEMBER_EMAIL>     
--service-account <TEAM_MEMBER_SERVICE_ACCOUNT> <TEAM_MEMBER_INSTANCE_NAME>
```

connect to a Datalab instance:

```
datalab connect --project <PROJECT> --zone <ZONE> <TEAM_MEMBER_INSTANCE_NAME>
```

Comment: This is not a correct solution, still Datalab user can connect to  the VM of each other using "--no-user-checking" !